# how to resume the application when click app icon launcher in cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am developing mobile application with [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org) phonegap. I am testing it on android platform right now later on ios . My problem is when I have the app running in background, and I click the launcher of this application it is re-initialized. What I want is to just **open the application from the launcher icon and continue running from where it is .**
I tried to set the attribute `keepRuning` in config.xml to **true** but it did not work.

```
   <preference name="keepRunning" value="true" />
```

This is the config.xml :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
     <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="com.coolappz.HTML5Application1" version="1.0.0">
        <name>HTML5Application1</name>
        <description>Cordova Application</description>
        <author email="info@com.coolappz" href="http://www.coolappz.com">user</author>
        <access origin="*"/>
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
        <preference name="keepRunning" value="true" />

    </widget>
```

**EDIT:**
For more details:

I have a counter that starts from **zero**  and increments by 1 every second . The counter resumes to increment in background **if I press home**. The problem is when I press the icon launcher of the application the counter resets from zero because the application is recreated.

I hope this makes the view more clear.

My question :

Can this be handled by cordova configuration or I need a plugin to do so.
Is that possible and how ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried  this solution and it worked for me

Add

```
     android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

for activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml , you can find it in               **projectName/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml**.

That's it .

Answer (score 0):

Update your config.xml for missing preferences. :

```
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
     <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.3.0" />    <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
   <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="false" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
   <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
   <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
   <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
   <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
   <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
   <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
   <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
   <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="10" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
   <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
   <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction " value="false"/>
```

Comment: The resume event fires when the native platform pulls the application out from the background. But when the launcher is clicked the application is recreated not resumed.

Comment: I'll share it in a moment

Comment: Thanks, Also check my updated post where I included config.xml of my app and there i am not finding this issue. So, Kindly include all the missing preferences even though looks useless. May be some of them are dependent.

Comment: Sorry I tried these configuration and the problem still exists

Comment: does your application run correctly on these configuration and resume after the lancher icon click ??